# how to do social sharing on vuejs without render server side

Tags: vue.js, seo, server-side-rendering, prerender

how can I share links to Facebook without rendering server-side? so far, when sharing on Facebook, just displaying below meta tags: title, description, URL, and the image didn't display. I have heard that the project structure should support render server-side to do that, but at the end of the release we could not create a new project structure that supporting RSS
So willing to listen to any discussion or suggestion from the community. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just detect the Facebook crawler (by its user agent) and redirect it to a basic page with the open-graph meta tags and nothing more. It doesn't care about the page itself (only the meta tags) so you have to do  the most basic server side rendering

Comment: Can I apply server-side rendering on an existing project? My co-worker said that we have to create a new project structure that supporting SSR, but I don't want, it will give some risk when we are preparing to move the project to the production server. @AlonEitan